# Adding a parameter to a worksheet event

Tags: vba, excel, event-handling, worksheet-function

I have found a macro that works really well to highlight the entire row that corresponds to a selected cell (whatever cell you select, the macro runs, and all rows are highlighted).  There are some drawbacks to this current iteration and I cannot seem to find a way to enact parameters I would want to limit the highlighting to a specific number of rows. Any ideas?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Const cnNUMCOLS As Long = 512
    Const cnHIGHLIGHTCOLOR As Long = 6  'default lt. yellow
    Static rOld As Range
    Static nColorIndices(1 To cnNUMCOLS) As Long
    Dim i As Long


    If Not rOld Is Nothing Then 'Restore color indices
        With rOld.Cells
            If .Row = ActiveCell.Row Then Exit Sub 'same row, don't restore
            For i = 1 To cnNUMCOLS
                .Item(i).Interior.ColorIndex = nColorIndices(i)
               Next i
        End With
    End If
    Set rOld = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Resize(1, cnNUMCOLS)
    With rOld
        For i = 1 To cnNUMCOLS
            nColorIndices(i) = .Item(i).Interior.ColorIndex
        Next i
        .Interior.ColorIndex = cnHIGHLIGHTCOLOR
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It would help to explain what you need to use the parameter for - typically event procedures don't have parameters other than the "built-in" ones.

Comment: I would generally just like for the highlighting to only occur in rows 11:54, however it is proving tedious to enact this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Const cnNUMCOLS As Long = 512
    Const cnHIGHLIGHTCOLOR As Long = 6  'default lt. yellow
    Static rOld As Range
    Static nColorIndices(1 To cnNUMCOLS) As Long
    Dim i As Long, bClear as Boolean, bInRange as Boolean

    bInRange = Not Application.Intersect(Me.Range("11:54"), Target) Is Nothing
    bClear = Not Application.Intersect(Me.Range("A6"), Target) Is Nothing

    'exit if selection is not in the first ten rows or A6
    If Not (bClear Or bInRange) Then Exit Sub

    If Not rOld Is Nothing Then 'Restore color indices
        With rOld.Cells
            If .Row = ActiveCell.Row Then Exit Sub 'same row, don't restore
            For i = 1 To cnNUMCOLS
                .Item(i).Interior.ColorIndex = nColorIndices(i)
               Next i
        End With
    End If

    If Not bInRange Then
        Set rOld = Nothing 
        Exit Sub  ' Exit if we're in A6
    End If

    Set rOld = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Resize(1, cnNUMCOLS)
    With rOld
        For i = 1 To cnNUMCOLS
            nColorIndices(i) = .Item(i).Interior.ColorIndex
        Next i
        .Interior.ColorIndex = cnHIGHLIGHTCOLOR
    End With

End Sub
```

Note: your code is assuming that only a single cell is selected - behaviour might not be as expected if the user selects multiple cells across >1 row

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!  I am trying the above sub and it appears to work exactly the same (in my environment the highlight occurs within any row even beyond rows 1:10.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Whoa. Not sure why this made a difference, but I saved and closed out the workbook and went back in with your code and it's working now. Thank you much!

Comment: if I wanted to be able to clear all highlighting when I clicked in a particular cell (say A6) can you think of a way to recall the previous cell's formatting and exit the highlighting?

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly and is proving already to make my work much less tedious.